# Condition for existence of Fourier transform?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, transformation, signal-processing

We can convert signal into frequency domain using Fourier transform. But I think we can't compute Fourier transform of any signal . Fourier transform  also should have some limits.

So I want to ask

> is there any condition for existence of Fourier transform ? What is the  limit for Fourier transform to converge?

Answer (score 0):

This is the  definition:
$$\hat{f}(\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\ e^{- 2\pi i x \xi}\,dx,$$   for any real number $ξ$.

We assume $f(x)$ is an integrable function, Lebesgue-measurable on the real line, and satisfy:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)| \, dx < \infty.$$

Comment: Well, maybe that's the beginning. But the Fourier transform can be defined for $f\in L^2$ and in the sense of distributions, for any locally integrable function, measures etc.